# Delete all records from a table

Tags: database, subsonic

How can I delete all records from a table using SubSonic?
The Delete method has three overloads, but each one expects some parameters.
And how can I delete records using a query (e.g. delete all records where column1 > 100)

Answer (score 3):

The following will delete all rows from the TempTable which have an Id of greater than 56:

```
new Delete().From(TempTable.Schema)
  .Where(TempTable.Columns.Id).IsGreaterThan(56)
  .Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Help is located at
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page
and many examples for this are in the tests included with the source.

```
int records = new Delete().From(Product.Schema)
    .Where("UnitPrice")
    .IsGreaterThan(42.00)
    .Execute();

// Delete all rows.
int records = new Delete().From(Product.Schema).Execute();
```